# Syntax for TypeScript class methods

Tags: typescript, typescript-eslint

In TypeScript I can define methods like a real method (`Foo`) or a property which gets a method assigned (`Baz`).

```
class TestClass {
    private mText: string = "test";
    public Baz = (): void => {
        console.log(this.mText);
    }

    public Foo(): void {
        console.log(this.mText);
    }
}
```

1. Are they equivalent?
2. Are there differences?
3. What syntax should I use?
4. Can I use `typescript-eslint` to forbid one of them?

Comment: it's totally up to you. And no need to forbid one.

Comment: Please note, multiple questions aren't recommendon on SO. Also question 3 is an opinion and 4 sounds like a separate question.

Comment: Thanks, @Julian. Let me remove the latter two question, then it is effectively only a single question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are not equivalent. `Baz` would not be on the prototype of `TestClass` (`Foo` would), but it would be a property on each instance.

Comment: the other thing to consider is that an arrow function's `this` context is explicitly bound to the class instance, but the method definition's `this` context is implicitly bound to the class instance. I.e. `const x = instance.Foo; x()` will not work, but `const y = instance.Baz; y()` will always work.

Answer (score 0):

As the accepted answer says, `Baz` is not on the prototype of `TestClass`, but `Foo` is. Following test code helped me understand what that means/implies:

```
class TestClass {
    public Baz = (): void => {
        console.log("Baz");
    }

    public Foo(): void {
        console.log("Foo");
    }
}

class SubClass1 extends TestClass { }
class SubClass2 implements TestClass {
    public Baz = (): void => {
        console.log("Baz of SubClass2");
    }

    public Foo(): void {
        console.log("Foo of SubClass2");
    }
}

TestClass.prototype.Baz = (): void => { console.log("Baz on prototype"); } // has no effect because Baz not on prototype
TestClass.prototype.Foo = (): void => { console.log("Foo on prototype"); }

const a = new TestClass();
const b = new TestClass();
const c = new TestClass();
const d = new SubClass1();
const e = new SubClass2();

a.Baz = (): void => { console.log("Baz of a"); }
a.Foo = (): void => { console.log("Foo of a"); }
b.Baz = (): void => { console.log("Baz of b"); }
b.Foo = (): void => { console.log("Foo of b"); }

console.log("a:");
a.Baz();
a.Foo();
console.log("b:");
b.Baz();
b.Foo();
console.log("c:");
c.Baz();
c.Foo();
console.log("d:");
d.Baz();
d.Foo();
console.log("e:");
e.Baz();
e.Foo();
```

You'll get following output:

```
a:
Baz of a
Foo of a
b:
Baz of b
Foo of b
c:
Baz
Foo on prototype
d:
Baz
Foo on prototype
e:
Baz of SubClass2
Foo of SubClass2
```

So tampering `TestClass.prototype.Baz` has no effect.
Changing `TestClass.prototype.Foo`, though, will change the default implementation of `Foo` for new instances.
However, each instance can both override `Foo` and `Baz` without affecting any other instances.